# Turing String/Int (putting them on the same line)

Tags: arrays, line, turing-lang

This is my current code:

```
var compMark : array 1 .. 5 of real
var name : array 1 .. 5 of string
var counter : int := -1
for i : 1 .. 5
    counter := counter + 1
    exit when (counter = 5)
    put "What is your name?"
    get name (i)
    if name (i) = "stop" then
        cls
        exit
    end if
    put "What is your mark in Computer Science?"
    get compMark (i)
    if compMark (i) < 0 or compMark (i) > 100 then
        cls
        put "Error"
        return
    end if
    put ""
end for
cls
put "Name \t\t Computer Science mark"
for i : 1 .. upper (name)
    put name (i)
end for
for j : 1 .. upper (compMark)
    put "\t\t", compMark (j)
end for
```

This is what the output is like:

---

Name            Computer Science Mark

name

name

name

75

35

98

---

How I want the output to be:

---

Name     Computer Science Mark

name     75

name     35

name     98

---

Anyone know how to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like

```
for i : 1 .. upper (name)
    put name (i)
end for
for j : 1 .. upper (compMark)
    put "\t\t", compMark (j)
end for
```

should be:

```
for i : 1 .. 5
    put name (i), "\t\t", compMark (i)
end for
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried doing something like that but failed, thankfully I think I get it now. This is kind of on topic but can you give me some tips on how to calculate the average of all the student's marks? Having some trouble

Comment: @Noctis calculate sum of all marks and then divide it by count (5 in your case)

Comment: Calculating the sum is where I'm stuck at, I currently have this:                                             for i : 1 .. 5
    put name (i), "\t\t", compMark (i)
    total := total + compMark(i)
    avg := total / counter
end for
put ""
put "The average of the class is ",avg : 0 : 2,"%."

Comment: average should be calculated outside the loop

Comment: So I should put     **total := total + compMark(i)
    avg := total / counter** outside of end for? it then says that "i" isn't found, and with the current code I have if all the marks are 50% it makes the average 62.50%

Comment: I said `average`, not `total`

Comment: ohhhh ok that makes sense in my head, but I'm confused as to how to get all the integers in my array and add them up into one variable, I've done averages before but not with arrays

Comment: `total := total + compMark(i)` - what this code does?

Comment: I tried to read off of tutorials and use my other code, which didn't relate to arrays so I'm experimenting right now so it doesn't do much right now

Comment: right now this code adds up every integer in array into single variable named `total`